# How to do toggle card(Design) in react-native?

Tags: react-native

> Hello, there! i'm new to the react-native programming. I'm trying to
>   do a toggle card as shown in below figure. But, i didn't find it easy
>   to make it as i'm beginner to react-native. Please find me the way to
>   design those toggle card. Thanks in advance....

[image: Toggle_Card]

Comment: Read about states in react. You can keep a variable in your state to tell whether to render the second card or not and on click of the arrow, you can toggle the value of your state variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use states and views to implement this very easily.
Also this library help you do it : [Accordion-React-Native](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-accordion)
You can even specify animations in this lib.

The code would go like htis

```
 <Accordion
        header={header}
        content={content}
        easing="easeOutCubic"
      />
```

where content and header would be like

```
 var content = (
      <View style={...}>
        <Text>This content is hidden in the accordion</Text>
      </View>
```